# No template or file for new android studio flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools, flutter-plugin

I have just started learning flutter and mobile app development
When I click create new flutter project it does not show any template and shows this -[create new flutter project wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfvN6.png)

My flutter doctor -v output is -[picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPuDv.png)

I'm not sure how to create a new flutter project properly and start the actual development of app.
Please help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the flutter app and then create the project. This will give you the default project to start.

- First download Flutter SDK for windows from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows).
- Then extract the zip in C:\src\flutter which would look like this:
  [image]
- Go to the `New project-->Flutter App` in android studio and enter the SDK path:
  [image]
- Then click next and then finish:
  [image]
- Go to the android studio setting and install `android sdk command-line tools`:

[image]

- Also after doing these steps go to `C:\src\flutter` and run `flutter_console.bat` file in which enter these commands:

`flutter doctor` to see everything is working correctly or not.

`flutter doctor --android-licenses` this command will check if all licenses are excepted or not. If not you should accept all.

[image]

Comment: I did that and got a blank project with no dart or any other file, also when I check the AVD and click play button it says unable to locate adb.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Also, ignore the unable to locate adb error.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just one more question in the step where you are creating a new project is it possible to make the project location in d drive (my SSD memory has less space whereas HDD has a lot of space)

Comment: Yes sure just change the project location field in image 3 to `D:\AnyFolder`. Also if I resolved your queries please mark it as answer.

Comment: It gives blank file when I make the project location in d drive

Comment: Please make a recording of the process of creating the flutter project and post it in the question or comment. As I'm unable to determine what's wrong in this process.

Comment: Also, when I was trying to run the project I made in my c drive it gives me an error -

Error running `pub global activate devtools`:
Pub failed to rename directory because access was denied.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.

Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:55543/tOmCoucAkV0=/

Do you have any ideas for this?

Comment: Can you share the path of the project you made in my c drive? As some paths have limited permissions.